# Solving Optics problem with and without differentiation result in different results

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

In a recent class of physics-calculus, I and my friends were discussing about a certain problem about optical lens. The problem was: "I a certain laboratory setup, there are a lens of focus $f$, an object of distance $s$ from the lens, and a resulting image of distance $s'$ from the lens. The object is moving at a speed of $v$ from the lens. Find the speed of the resulting image, $v'$.

[image]

Our class went on and solve the problem. However, we didn't come to the same conclusion. Here is where we do agree: 
$$
\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s'} \\
\frac{1}{s'}=\frac{1}{f}-\frac{1}{s} \\ 
\frac{1}{s'}=\frac{s-f}{sf} \\ 
s' = \frac{sf}{s-f}
$$

This is where the solutions diverge:

## Solution 1

$$
\frac{d}{dt}s' = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{sf}{s-f} \\
\frac{d}{dt}s' = f\frac{(s-f)v-sv}{(s-f)^2} \\ 
v' = \frac{-f^2v}{(s-f)^2} \\
$$

## Solution 2

From: $ v=s/t$ 
$$
v' = \frac{s'}{t}=\frac{sf}{t(s-f)} \\
v' = \frac{vf}{s-f}
$$

Both solutions are consistent with dimensional analysis, surprisingly. 
**So, how does one explain this inconsistency?**

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I just noticed that the lens outline in your image is *just slightly* wobbly. Was this maybe scanned and vector-traced from a printed version, or did someone actually draw that lens *by hand*? o_O

Comment: @Ilmari Yeah, it was vector-traced from a printed version, with MS Powerpoint. Not the ideal program, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 2 has a problem right at the beginning: the correct definition of velocity is $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$, not $v=\frac st$. The two expressions are, in general, only equivalent for objects moving at a constant velocity (and located at $s=0$ at time $t=0$). But in your system, $s'$ is not a linear function of $s$, so the object and the image *cannot* both be moving at a constant velocity.

Solution 1 looks reasonable at a glance, but it's a bit hard to follow, so let me just work out the solution with more detail and see what comes out.  We'll start with:

$$v' = \frac{d}{dt} s' = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{sf}{s-f}$$

Clearly, since $f$ is constant, $\frac{d}{dt} sf = vf$ and $\frac{d}{dt} (s-f) = \frac{d}{dt} s = v$.  Thus, applying the [quotient rule](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule), we have:

$$v' = \frac{vf \cdot (s-f) - sf \cdot v}{(s-f)^2} = \frac{vfs - vf^2 - sfv}{(s-f)^2} = \frac{-vf^2}{(s-f)^2} = -v \left(\frac{f}{s-f}\right)^2$$

just as in your solution 1.